# Scrapy security pause and start

Tags: scrapy

I know that I can use the command

scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1

To record the crawler's running information to ensure that it can be restarted after the crawler is paused, it will continue to crawl in the currently paused position.

But if the crawler runs silently in the background on the server, there is no way to execute ctrl+c

The way I know is that ps -df finds the crawler's process and kill -s 9 id in a way that forces the crawler to close. But this will inevitably interrupt some of the crawler's finishing work. JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1 will be lost the next time it is started. What can I do to stop the crawler safely?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/406926/172753

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation provided by kill, you can use kill -2 pid to safely stop the crawler equivalent to ctrl+c